# Error when deploying a hello world smart contract with hardhat - could not detect network

Tags: contract-deployment, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I'm following this official Ethereum's [tutorial](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/hello-world-smart-contract/) to create a hello world.

In this tutorial we need to use alchemy, which doesn't supports ropsten anymore, the only test network avaliable in alchemy is goerli.

So, to continue the tutorial, I replaced all ropsten content with goerli.

But, when I try to deploy the smart contract, with:

```
npx hardhat --network goerli run scripts/deploy.js
```

I got the following error:

```
Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (/home/caio/Área de trabalho/hello-world-eth/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (/home/caio/Área de trabalho/hello-world-eth/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:281:20)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.<anonymous> (/home/caio/Área de trabalho/hello-world-eth/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/src.ts/json-rpc-provider.ts:483:23)
    at step (/home/caio/Área de trabalho/hello-world-eth/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.throw (/home/caio/Área de trabalho/hello-world-eth/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
    at rejected (/home/caio/Área de trabalho/hello-world-eth/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
  reason: 'could not detect network',
  code: 'NETWORK_ERROR',
  event: 'noNetwork'
}
```

My hardhat.config.js code:

```
/** 
* @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig 
*/

require('dotenv').config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");

const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
  defaultNetwork: "goerli",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    goerli: {
      url: API_URL,
      accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`]
    }
  },
}
```

I just copied the example code from the tutorial and replaced ropsten with goerli.

Also, this file exact the same as seen in this Alchemy's [tutorial](https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/hello-world-smart-contract), that is an "updated" version of the ethereum's tutorial, but using goerli.

*UPDATE*

I found the error, the alchemy's goerli url was wrong in the .env file, already fixed and working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the hardhat docs, the command is `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network <network-name>`, so it's `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli`. Also, make sure you have the network, chainId, url, and accounts set up in the hardhat.config.js file.

See: https://hardhat.org/tutorial/deploying-to-a-live-network

Comment: I just copied the tutorial's example code inside the hardhat.config.js file and replaced the ropsten with goerli.

Comment: Using the correct command still gives me the same error.

Comment: did you include the goerli chainId?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I found the error, I forgot to replace the eth-ropsten with eth-goerl in the .env file. Running the command now works!